# Sum of $\sin$ and $\cos$

Tags: trigonometry

We are given a trigonometric equation to solve: $$a\sin x+b\cos x=c$$ with $a,b,c$ nonzero real numbers.

We are also given that $$a\sin x+b\cos x=R\sin(x+\varphi)$$ with $R^2=a^2+b^2$ and $\tan\varphi=\frac{b}{a}$.

My problem is, how can we know the correct sign of $R$ and how can we know which $\varphi$ to take from the whole total number of solutions for $\varphi$ (after using calculator to find the $\varphi$, we have the solutions $\varphi=180k+\tan^{-1}\frac{b}{a})$.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Conventionally we take $R\ge0$

In fact, $R=0\iff a=b=0$

Now expanding the RHS and equating the coefficients of $\sin x,\cos x$

$\cos\phi=\dfrac aR$ and $\sin\phi=\dfrac bR$

So from the signs of $a,b;$ the signs of $\sin\phi,\cos\phi$ can be determined using [all-sin-tan-cos-rule](http://www.mathymind.com/all-sin-tan-cos-rule-in-trigonometry/)

In fact, $\sin\phi/cos\phi=\dfrac bR/\dfrac aR$ is oversimplified to determine the actual value of $\phi$

Comment: are you sure we always take R to be positive?

Answer (score 0):

Expanding $R\sin(x+\phi) = R\cos \phi\sin x + R\sin \phi \cos x$ you see that you need to have
$$
R\cos \phi = a\\
R\sin \phi = b 
$$

Any $(R,\phi)$ such as these equations are satisfied is convenient. In other words: there is not only one solution to your problem: if $(R,\phi) $ is one solution then so is $(-R,\phi+\pi)$.

Using the relation $\cos^2 + \sin^2 = 1$, you can always take $R =\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$ and
 $$\phi = {\text{sign}(b)} \arccos\frac aR$$

Comment: and which φ do we put in cosφ or sinφ to find the R ?

Comment: You put any $\phi$ which is such as $R \cos \phi = a, R\sin \phi  =b$.

Comment: but we don't know the R! you have to start from something! either first find the φ and then the R, or first the R and then the φ! you are not answering me well! and the problem is to determine the sign of the R from somewhere that doesn't involve the φ (since you don't know it) *OR* to determine the φ from somewhere that doesn't involve R!

Comment: see my edit!${}{{}}$

Comment: mookid, again you do not tell me the steps! what do I find first and how, what do I find second and how!

Comment: First, compute $R$ and then, compute $\phi$. Everything is in my last edit, in the last two lines.

Answer (score 0):

i think it must be
$\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\sin(x)+\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\cos(x)\right)\sqrt{a^2+b^2}=R\sin(x+\phi)$